# Realistic physic settings in Box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to make a game with libgdx and Box2D.
I have some problems in finding 'good' or correct physics settings.

Either the physics seem to be very slow (especially gravity) or I need to use extreme values when appling force to an object and even then it has little effect.

---

This are my current world and step settings:

```
static final float BOX_STEP=1/60f; 

//World world = new World(new Vector2(0, -9.81f), true);  // With the settings my objects seem to be under water and react very slow
World world = new World(new Vector2(0, -200f), true); //<-- current settings
```

---

Player-Object settings:

```
...
_fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();  
_fixtureDef.shape       = _shape;
_fixtureDef.density     = 2.5f;
_fixtureDef.friction    = 1.0f;
_fixtureDef.restitution = 0;  
...
```

---

Applying force to the player for jumping

```
    @Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) 
{
    if ((keycode == Keys.UP) && (!_pp.isJumping()))
    {
        _pp.getBody().applyForceToCenter(new Vector2(0, 999000000), true);
        // Even with this high value the player barely jumps

        _pp.setJumping(true);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any advice on how to set up physic settings correctly are really appreciated :).

Comment: Read the manual and scale your world, otherwise you will get a maximum speed of something like 120px/s

Comment: @noone So I have to map my 'large' sprites to the physic bodys which is fine. I scaled down my physics world and this seems to work much better now. One problem remains. I have set the gravity to `-9.81` and my player size to `5`. With this settings the player still seems to be under water. I can achieve better results when setting the players `gravityScale` to `5.0f`. Is this good practice? The docs say that increased gravity can decrease stability.

Comment: @user1567896 to let you know: Box2D works with 1 unit = 1 meter, so your player is 5 meters tall.

Comment: A size of 5 means that your player is about 5 meters. The manual says you should keep your body sizes somewhere between 0.1m and 10m. It is still in this range, but you should make it smaller still. I use always 1m for my player. And in the end it's just about making it look right. However you achieve that doesn't matter that much. A lot of things are faked in games...

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I changed my player size to 1 meter. Nevertheless I still have this gravity problem. Is it a good idea to set `gravityScale` of my player to `5.0f`? Is there any other way to achieve a more realistic gravity?

Comment: Realistic gravity would be something like `new World(new Vector2(0, -10f), true);`.  Your gravity is about 20x that of earth.